# Swift: Passing callbacks to struct instance

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to do something along the lines of the pseudo code below:

```
struct Foo {
  let BarInstance = Bar(Callback: CallBarInstance)

  func CallBarInstance() -> Void {
    BarInstance.FunctionToCall()
  }
}

struct Bar {
  var Callback: () -> Void

  func FunctionToCall() -> Void {
    print("Hello")
  }

  // More code that calls Callback
}
```

I get the error that I can't convert (Foo)->()->Void to ()->Void. I think I understand this is because the instance of Foo is being passed in as it is a member function. I figured it could then be made a static function that calls but getting access to the member variables felt hacky - is there a good way to get the functionality I want in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do something dangerous here, and Swift is stopping you from doing it.

In this line:

```
let BarInstance = Bar(Callback: CallBarInstance)
```

You are leaking an uninitialised `self` to `Bar`. Why? Because at the point in time when `Bar.init` is called, `Foo` is not be fully initialised. Namely, what is the value of `BarInstance` at this point? It is undefined. Yet you are trying to pass `self.CallbarInstance` to `Bar.init`!

Imagine what could happen if this were allowed. `Bar.init` had called the passed in function directly, before it returns. Now we have a very weird situation: `CallBarInstance` actually makes use of the value of `BarInstance` in its implementation, but what's the value of `BarInstance`? `Bar.init` hasn't returned so it's undefined!

The error message is a bit unclear though. Swift treats `CallBarInstance` as a `(Foo) -> () -> Void` in this situation (as if you were calling it as `Foo.CallBarInstance`), because `self` is unavailable.

You can kind of fix it by initialising `BarInstance` with some other value first, then assigning the intended `Bar` instance, but I don't know whether this will produce your intended behaviour or not.

```
struct Foo {
  var BarInstance = Bar(Callback: {})

    init() {
        BarInstance = Bar(Callback: CallBarInstance)
    }

  func CallBarInstance() -> Void {
    BarInstance.FunctionToCall()
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution does work but I feel like I'm not doing this in the proper Swift way. Thanks for the help